# Должен ли я сливать master в ветку, перед слитием ветки в master?

Tags: git, svn

Ранее я работал в SVN и перед сливом любого бранча в trunk, я сначала сливал trunk в бранч, коммитил бранч, потом переключался на trunk и сливал бранч в trunk. Т.е. были вот такие действия:

1. Переключаюсь на бранч
2. Сливаю trunk в бранч
3. коммичу бранч
4. Переключаюсь на trunk
5. Сливаю бранч в trunk
6. Коммичу trunk

Теперь я перекатился на git, и смотрю видео о его использовании. И нигде не упоминается способ описанный мной выше. Т.е. люди просто сразу сливают бранчи в master. Сразу скажу я не планирую использовать коммандрую строку, для работы с git, а использую SourceTree.
Дак, вот мой вопрос, как люди поступают то?
Как быть в случае долгоживущих веток, все равно же время от вермени в них нужно Master сливать, что бы синхронизировать код?

Comment: Способ, который вы описали, я встречал в паре источников как best-practice. Думаю, вам стоит продолжать делать так же. Лично я тоже пользуюсь этим методом - сперва подтягиваю изменения целевой ветки, резолвлю конфликты, тестирую результат, и лишь затем мержу к целевой ветке

Comment: @cauf Почему не `git pull --rebase ...`? История намного чище, вам же более понятно что происходит в топик-бранче.

Answer (score 2):

Если взять лопату и копнуть внутрь, сравнивая эти два способа, то разницы не будет. В гит на самом деле есть два мастера - один локальный, один серверный. Когда Вы делаете локальный мердж ветки в мастер, то получится новый коммит, на который будет указывать обе ветки. Если же смержить мастер себе, а потом себя в мастер, то по факту, результат не будет отличатся. Просто вторым мержем произойдет fastforward и все таким же. Видимо поэтому никто и не делает двойной работы.

> Сразу скажу я не планирую использовать коммандрую строку, для работы с git, а использую SourceTree. Дак, вот мой вопрос, как люди поступают то?

нет, люди обычно так не поступают. А которые поступают, то плачут. Я встречался с тремя багами в этом туле. От одного чуть не был сорван релиз.

Comment: В 97% задач командная строка для гита не нужна и неудобна.

Comment: крайне не соглашусь с таким мнением. Особенно, когда в Source tree видишь разломанное дерево коммитов. (хотя оно впорядке)

Comment: [Fork](https://git-fork.com/) лучше, потому что SourceTree какой-то тормоз. Но косяков с деревом не встречал там.

Comment: 49.99 ? серьезно? за очередную поделку??? пытался найти в багтрекерре sourcetree эту багу, но видимо я не умею в таком искать

Comment: Хм.. Там раньше было написано free. Кажется, что-то поменяли...

Comment: оно free для оценки

Comment: Поменяли ((( Раньше было совсем free.

Comment: @KoVadim Вы меня, прямо расстроили с SourceTree. Дело в том, что ранее я пользовался TortoiseSVN, и за все время использования, мне только пару раз пришлось обратиться к коммандной строке svn для совсем специфических задач. И я ожидал, что один из самых популярных GUI для git будет работать так же, прям чтоб сел и поехал. Мне от него нужно то, что бы мог коммитить, апдейтить, сливать, ветки делать. В общем рутинные, ежедневные задачи.

Comment: да все ок. я всегда коммитю через консоль исключительно. а если нужно посмотреть дифф перед коммитом (ну если он случайно оказался супер сложным), то использую meld

Comment: @МаксКливер а кто мешает использовать TortoiseGit?

Comment: здравый смысл? :)